# DLookup based on date ranges

Tags: ms-access, lookup, lookup-tables

I'm an ms access novice and i'm in the process of building a simple relational database. I have two tables, one containing a date field and another table containing a range for the dates and the value i want to return based on the date range. In excel i would use the LOOKUP function but in access, the only options seems to be to use the "DLookup" function.

[image]

the destination table has a column with the dates. So far, the expression that i've got which keeps returning an error is

```
DLookup(DLookUp([KR_DB]![DPL_TargetMonth],[SeasonFY],[KR_DB]![DPL_TargetMonth] Between [SeasonFY]![SeasonDateFrom] And [SeasonFY]![SeasonDateTo])
```

I don't know how to write the proper syntax for this.

Comment: The way to deal with this within relational databases is to create a **query**. Stop thinking MS Excel and start exploring MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the SeasonFY ID as foreign key in KR_DB would be the relational approach. However, DLookup could be like:

```
SELECT KR_DB.*, 
DLookup("Season", "SeasonFY", "#" & [DPL_TargetMonth] & "# BETWEEN SeasonDateFrom AND SeasonDateTo") AS Season
FROM KR_DB;
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! i do want to use the relational approach but i'm teaching myself how to do this and i struggled finding a way to use a foreign key based on a to-from date range from within the table.